# Loading data in another view on menu item click within ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I am new to AngularJS. I have a rest service which provides json response and I use this response to build a navigation menu. This response has following structure.

- Menu Item A

  - Menu Item A1

    - Menu Item A1-1
  - Menu Item A2

    - Menu Item A2-1
- Menu Item B

  - Menu Item B1

    - Menu Item B1-1
    - Menu Item B1-2
  - Menu Item B2

I am able to build this structure recursively using a custom directive.

```
module.directive("tree", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    scope: {menu: '='},
    template:
    '<ul>' +
      '<li ng-transclude ng-repeat="menuItem in menu.menuItems" ng-controller="MyItemController">' +
        '<a ng-click="getTitles(menuItem.taxId);">{{ menuItem.text }} {{ menuItem.childCount }}</a>' +
        '<tree menu="menuItem.subMenu"></tree>'+
      '</li>' +
    '</ul>',
    compile: function(tElement, tAttr, transclude) {
      var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
      var compiledContents;
      return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
        if(!compiledContents) {
          compiledContents = $compile(contents, transclude);
        }
        compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
          iElement.append(clone);
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the controller to load this menu json

```
var module = angular.module('myapp',[]);

module.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('<link to rest service for loading menu>').
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.menu = data;
  });

});
```

here is the item controller for each menu item

```
module.controller("MyItemController", function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.getTitles = function (taxId) {

    $http.get('<link to rest service for loading the detail for clicked menu item>').
    success(function(data) {
      $scope.titlesList = data; // This is where I get the data from menu item click but I don't know how to use titlesList as the scope here is isolated one for each menu item.
    });
  };

});
```

And here is the html

```
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4" ng-controller="MyController">

      <nav id="menuwrapper">

        <tree menu="menu"></tree>

      </nav>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <!-- This is where I want to load the content when I get response from json after clicking menu item -->
    </div>

  </div>
```

It works fine till calling the rest service when the menu item is clicked. But I don't understand how can I reference the data loaded from json due to ngRepeat which generates separate controller and scope for each item.

I am assuming this is a very common task and there may be a different and better approach to do this which I do not know. So, please feel free to suggest any best practices.

Comment: I'd suggest to remove the `ng-controller="myItemController"` you don't need a controller for each one, then put `MyController` in the `row` div and control everything from there.

Comment: @Michelem could you please elaborate? How can I call click method? Can you please make your suggested changes to the code?